# something wrong with my float operation

Tags: c++, operators

i must be missing something, whats wrong with this?

```
float controlFrameRate = 1/60;
```

It should be assigning something like 0.0166666667 but its coming out 0.00000 etc. is visual studio just lying to me?

Comment: Just a side note: if your framerate is 60 FPS, you should call your variable `controlFrameInterval`, because `controlFrameRate` would be 60, and not 1/60.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because `1/60` is an integer, which is 0 because integer division truncates. This is used to initialize the float, giving `0.` You can fix it by making the RHS expression a float in the first place:

```
float controlFrameRate = 1.0f/60;
```

of

```
float controlFrameRate = 1/60.0f;
```

In C++, literals such as `1`, `42` etc. are `int`, `1.0`, `3.1416` are `double`, and the `f` in `1.0f` makes the literal a `float`. Note that the `f` could have been omitted in the examples above. However, assigning a double to a float could be problematic if the double's value goes beyond the range of a float.

Answer (score 3):

A division of an integer by another integer yields an integer, and is a truncating operation. You'll get the value that is less than or equal to the actual value.

Make at least one of the constants floating-point to fix it:

```
float controlFrameRate = 1.0 / 60;
float controlFrameRate = 1 / 60.0;
float controlFrameRate = 1.0 / 60.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
 float controlFrameRate = 1.f/60;
```

or

```
 float controlFrameRate = 1/60.f;
```

or

```
 float controlFrameRate = 0.1f/6;
```

;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `1/60.0`. otherwise you will not get `float` result.