# Division and floating points

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-accuracy

Can Anyone help me why x2 prints zero. 
I guess because of floating point representation X1 is rounded off, is there way to keep the precession.

```
long double x1, x2;
x1= 0.087912088; // Note: 360/4095 = 0.087912088
x2 = 360/4095;
printf("%Lf, %Lf \n",x1, x2);
```

Result:

```
x1 =0.087912
x2= 0.000000
```

Comment: chris and Levon thanks for the reply. Is there a way to increase the precession.

Comment: To actually store more digits, you'd need an arbitrary-precision library. Just displaying more can be done as Levon says, or with `std::setprecision` in C++.

Comment: @chris I'm working on low level motor control code is C on a QNX embedded system. I will keep that in mind for c++ code.

Comment: To make it less confusing for the others in the future, consider these two dictionary entries: [precession](http://www.tfd.com/precession), [precision](http://www.tfd.com/precision).

Comment: possible duplicate of [something wrong with my float operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872053/something-wrong-with-my-float-operation)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is *integer truncation* .. you are dividing two integers => the result will be another integer with the fractional part thrown away. (So for instance in the case when the real result of an integer division would be 3.9, truncation would make it 3 (ie. it doesn't round)).

In your case, if you change this to:

```
x2 = 360 / 4095.0;  /* one of the operands now has a decimal point */
```

you'll get

```
0.087912, 0.087912
```

as output.

I.e., as soon as *one or both* of the operands of the division operator `/` are float/doubles, the result will be too (i.e., it will be "promoted" to float/double). So I could have changed `x2` to

```
x2 = 360.0 / 4095.0;
```

or

```
x2 = 360.0 / 4095;
```

and would have gotten the same result as above.

As mentioned by @chris just using a `.` is sufficient too.

Re your question above about precision:

You are already working with long doubles .. I don't think internally you can change anything unless you use some special library, but you can certainly display more digits. E.g.,

```
  printf("%Lf, %.20Lf \n",x1, x2);
```

will yield

```
  0.087912, 0.08791208791208791895
```

Finally, as @edA-qa mort-ora-y reminds us, you can also *cast* values to certain types, but it matters *when* you do it. A simple example (note that the values end up as `float` *after* the assignment in any case since `v` is a `float`):

```
float v = 0;
                     /* values shown are BEFORE assignment */
v = (5 / 2);         /* value is 2 due to integer truncation before assignment */
v = (float) (5 / 2); /* 2.0 as integer division occurs 1st, then cast to float */
v = (float) 5 / 2;   /* 2.5 since 5 becomes 5.0 through casting first. */
```

Comment: Just a dot at the end suffices as well.

Comment: @chris Thanks .. I didn't realize that .. learned something new :) I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: You can also cast to a float, which is helpful if you need to promote a variable and not a constant. `float(a)` , `double(4)`

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y good point, thanks for the reminder, I'll add a note about casting to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Built-in operators work on objects of the same type. The result is the same type as the parameters. In this case the division is done on two integers and thus the result is an integer.

```
x2 = 360/4096;
//   int/int  = int
```

Thus I would expect a result of 0.

If the operators on a built-in type are different the one will promoted so that they have the same type (and the result is also that type). So what you want is:

```
x2 = 1.0 * 360/4095;  // or 360.0/4095

// This is
    double * int / int

==> (double * double)/int
==> (double * double)/double
```