# Weird rounding in C

Tags: c, double, precision, rounding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C programming division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906722/c-programming-division)

in the following code example the result should yield 130.0 yet once compiled, I get 129.0. Is the right hand side not producing enough precision to get an accurate result? Is there a way around this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    double sum = ((117+130)/3) + ((130+13)/3);
    printf("sum: %f\n", sum);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are observing is the result of  **integer truncation**. When doing integer division with two integer operands, the result will be another integer, with the *fractional* part thrown away. Note that this is different from rounding, e.g, with truncation 3.8 will become 3.

This will give you your expected output:

```
double sum = ((117+130) / 3.0) + ((130+13) / 3.0);
```

since we divide by `3.0` rather than `3`.

I.e., if at least *one*, or *both* of the operands in an integer division is a float type, the result will be a float. (Note that I'm using float/double here somewhat interchangeably with regard to `int`s and truncations)

In addition to appending a `.` or `.0` to values (`.0` will generate a `double`, while `.0f` will generate a `float` - as pointed out by @Morwenn's helpful comment below), we can also explicitly cast ints to floats, but it matters *when* we do it. A simple example (note that the values end up as `float` *after* the assignment in this example in any case since `v` is a `float`):

```
float v = 0;
                     /* values shown are BEFORE assignment */
v = (5 / 2);         /* value is 2 due to integer truncation before assignment */
v = (float) (5 / 2); /* 2.0 as integer division occurs 1st, then cast to float */
v = (float) 5 / 2;   /* 2.5 since 5 becomes 5.0 through casting first. */
```

I borrowed the above example from [Division and floating points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11060283/1209279)

Comment: Just a small detail, but `.0` will generate a `double` while `.0f` will generate a `float`.

Comment: @Morwenn .. that's a good point. I guess I was speaking in more general terms where I meant to include both doubles/floats, but I'll make a note just to be sure and not cause any confusion for anyone down the line. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Although you declare `sum` as `float`, the right-hand-side of the operation consists of ONLY integers, so it's treated as an integer expression, and divisions are truncated. Try

```
double sum = ((117 + 130) / 3.0) + ((130 + 13) / 3.0);
```

instead.